# SSIS Assembly causing System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

Scenario:

1) I'm moving **SSIS** from a **Windows 2008 r2 server with SQL 2012 (@ Amazon)** to a **Windows 2012 server with SQL 2012 (@ Azure)**

Windows 2008 Config (production server)

1) A strongly typed dll was compiled with **vs2012**.  It has been  in use on the 2008 server for about 14 months. The dll is called from Script Tasks and from Script Components. (both vb not c#) The dll is called from 5 dtsx's.

2) `\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe` was used to configure the dll into the gac.

3) For some reason, I configured both a x64 and msil version of the dll. I'm not certain why I did this but it is a production server so I'm not inclined to uninstall / reinstall to test.

4) The msil version is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies`

Windows 2012 Config (future production server)

1) I installed the dll exactly the way the dll is installed on the Windows 2008 box

2) The dll works fine from Script Tasks

3) The dll does not work from Script Components, the same error message is produced which is:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'NSWebService, Version=2.2012.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2e561c72c5209961' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Would anyone have suggestions on how to debug / determine why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is that you have a reference to NSWebService in your assembly and that NSWebService is not installed on the new server.
The fix is to make sure NSWebService is in the GAC on the new server.